The 'awesome_notifications' channel sent a message from native to Flutter on a non-platform thread
I am using awesome_notifications package in flutter to schedule notifications. In iOS, when the app schedules notifications, it gives the following error on the console:
[ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(1055)] The 'awesome_notifications' channel sent a message from native to Flutter on a non-platform thread. Platform channel messages must be sent on the platform thread. Failure to do so may result in data loss or crashes, and must be fixed in the plugin or application code creating that channel.
See https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/platform-channels#channels-and-platform-threading for more information.
I do not have any idea how to fix this error.
I have also tried the example application in the official documentation of awesome_notifications package. It gives the same error.

same here, any solutions ?

It doesn't impact the app's functionality, but it also cannot be removed.
